# How to load content from another php page using jQuery .load() function?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

I'm using a simple .load() function from Jquery to load a div element with id from another file in the same folder when changing the selected option in selector. But I can't make it work. Nothing happens when I change the selected option the server gives error "No such file or directory" and My alert ("Before load") does work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <select id="productType" onchange="load_special_data()">
            <option id="Book" selected>Book</option>
            <option id="DVD">DVD</option>
            <option id="Furniture">Furniture</option>
        </select>
        
        <div id="specialData"></div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function()
        {
            jQuery("#productType").change(load_special_data());
        });
        function load_special_data()
        {
            var selected_id = $("#productType option:selected").attr("id");
    
            alert("Before load");
            try {
                jQuery("#specialData").load('form_special_data.php #Book', null, function (responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
                    alert(textStatus); // see what the response status is
                });
            } catch (e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
    
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Content of form_special_data.php:

```
<div id="Book">
    <label for="weight">Weight (KG) </label>
    <input type="number" required class="form-control" name="weight" id="weight">
    <small>Please provide book weight in KG</small>
</div>
<div id="Furniture">
    <label for="height">Height (CM) </label>
    <input type="number" required class="form-control" name="height" id="height">
    <label for="width">Width (CM) </label>
    <input type="number" required class="form-control" name="width" id="width">
    <label for="length">Length (CM) </label>
    <input type="number" required class="form-control" name="length" id="length">
</div>
```

Comment: What does `alert(textStatus)` show?

Comment: `jQuery("#productType").change(load_special_data());` is wrong, you need to pass a function _reference_ as parameter - but you are _calling_ the function here instead. (And are thereby effectively assigning its _return value_ as the event handler callback "function", but your function does not have a return value to begin with.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't invoke the `load_special_data` function more than once.

Remove the `onchange="load_special_data()"`, and leave it like this:

```
<select id="productType">
```

Put all the JQuery related functions inside the `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ...`

Like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#productType").change(load_special_data());

    function load_special_data() {
        var selected_id = $("#productType option:selected").attr("id");

        alert("Before load");
        try {
            jQuery("#specialData").load('form_special_data.php #Book', null, function (responseText, textStatus, xhr) {
            alert(textStatus); // see what the response status is
            });
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }

    }
});
```

About the *No such file or directory* error, that's one of the easiests errors to fix. Verify that the file name and path are correct.

Finally, I don't know what's your final goal here, but I'd use AJAX instead of "load" because it's more practical and easier to use.

Comment: I deleted onchange="load_special_data() as you mentioned and passed load_special_data by reference to .change() as mentioned in comments, now it is working if I'm only loading content from same page but the error _No such file or directory_ still exist when loading the other file and I verified the file name and since both files are in same folder I think the path should only include the file name.